# Remove 8765 port from cakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am new in cake php I am using CakePHP 3.0 for Application development.
For my application I just use `bin/cake server` command an open project at url: http://localhost:8765.

But now I have to move my app to client server, please help me to remove 8765 port from CakePHP 3.0 application and run it without using port.

**Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: You shouldn't be using `bin/cake server` on a live server. Just configure your vhost as you normally would for a website.